# Watch file create events using ruby guard gem

Tags: ruby, guard

How do I watch for only the file create events in a particular folder using Ruby `guard` gem

Answer (score 1):

You can create an inline Guard directly within your `Guardfile`:

```
module ::Guard
  class Test < Guard
    def run_on_additions(paths)
      puts "New paths: #{ paths.inspect }"
    end
  end
end

guard 'test'
```

You'll find the docs for the Guard plugin base class on [rubydoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/gems/guard/Guard/Guard). If your inline Guard grows, you can create your own Guard plugin gem, see the Wiki page on how to [create a Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Create-a-guard)

Another option is to use [Listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) directly, which is the file listener that was extracted from Guard.